# Check if user writes text in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am programming a chat in C# and I need a function to check if text in textbox is changed. It can be done with TextChanged event but I need to check it only at start of writing.

```
private void messageText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    chatApp.WriteChatLine(userName + "is typping...");
}
```

This code writes a chat message every time the text is changed. How to restrict it only for the first time when the user started to write a text into a textbox? I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I can't get it working. Thank you for help!

Comment: When text length is exactly 1 character? No extra code needed.

Comment: Have you thought about removing the event handler after the first time? Ex: `messageText.TextChanged -= messageText_TextChanged;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unsubscribe from event handler:

```
private void messageText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    chatApp.WriteChatLine(userName + "is typping...");
    messageText.TextChanged -= messageText_TextChanged;
}
```

This event handler will be executed once, and then removed from handlers list. Thus further changes of text will not fire event (if there is no other subscribers) or this particular handler will not be executed.

UPDATE: As @karim noted, you will probably need to automatically reset this message after message is sent, or user stopped typing, or user deleted everything. It can be done with timer component (set it's Interval to value you want *typing* message be displayed after user stopped typing)

```
private void messageText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // if timer already running, then don't update status
    if (!timer.Enabled)
        chatApp.WriteChatLine(userName + "is typping...");

    timer.Stop(); // restart timer
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearStatus();        
}

private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // send message
    ClearStatus();
}

private void ClearStatus()
{
     chatApp.WriteChatLine(""); // some code which clears status message
     timer.Stop(); // stop timer
}
```

You can simplify this code, by creating property which will handle status update and timer starting/stopping:

```
private void messageText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsUserTyping = true;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsUserTyping = false;
}

private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // send message
    IsUserTyping = false;
}

private bool IsUserTyping 
{
    get { return timer.Enabled; }
    set {
        if (value)
        {
            if (!IsUserTyping)
                chatApp.WriteChatLine(userName + "is typping...");

            timer.Stop();
            timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            chatApp.WriteChatLine("");
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: He'll need much more extra code to attach handler again when user finally send message and when **he deletes all inserted text then start typing again**...

Comment: I would also use a timer to resubscribe to the event a few seconds latter. If not, the code will work only at the very first character typed, and not for further chat messages.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti send button click event handler: `messageText.TextChanged += messageText_TextChanged`

Comment: @karim agree, timer is a good solution (Skype uses this approach)

Comment: Yes but you have to handle other case too (delete text without sending). It may be done with a timer but IMO it's kind of overkill for this task (if this event will just write a line in chat room).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I've updated answer with Skype-like behavior for message text changing

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally I get it working in "simplified" variant. This helped me a lot in understanding of those "processes"

Answer (score 0):

You could have a sentinel variable to detect if the change has already fired once or not, something like so:

```
bool textboxChanged = false;

private void messageText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!textboxChanged) //if not changed
    {
        chatApp.WriteChatLine(userName + "is typping...");
    }
}
```

So the event still gets fired but it won't do anything until you change the sentinel variable. This has the extra value of allowing you to reset the sentinel variable later on if need be without having to worry about resubscribing to the event.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest version would be

```
bool wasUserTyping = false;
private void messageText_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
     wasUserTyping = true;
}

private void messageText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e){
    if(wasUserTyping){
          //Yaaay!! User did type
    }
}
```